# OpenAPI cookie parameter serialization

Tags: serialization, openapi

I'm trying to implement spec-compliant parameter serialization for OpenAPI cookie parameters.

My only source for this is the docs: https://swagger.io/docs/specification/serialization/#cookie

**In the description I'm seeing this line**:

> An optional explode keyword controls the array and object serialization

However the table below only defines array and object serialization, when `explode` is `false`.

**What does this mean?**:

- Is cookie serialization with `explode` = `true` defined? If so could you please link docs?
- If not, am I correct in saying, that `explode` = `true` basically "disables" array and object serialization, and has no effect on primitive serialization?
- If neither of these, then what is the situation with `explode`?

I hope an OpenAPI expert can shed some light on this, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cookie serialization is defined but unfortunately not well thought out, as a result some forms of it don't make much sense. One of the specification authors [admits](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/1528#issuecomment-379584566) that they "never really thought anyone would go through the trouble of describing *objects* in *cookies* in an *exploded* way".

In a nutshell, cookie serialization follows the same rules as [query parameters with `style: form`](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/serialization/#query).

When using `explode: true`:

- A cookie parameter named `param` with the array value `[3, 4, 5]` would be sent as:

  ```
  Cookie: param=3&param=4&param=5
  ```
- A cookie parameter named `param` with the object value `{"foo": "test", "bar": 5}` would be sent as:

  ```
  Cookie: foo=test&bar=5
  ```

  Note that the parameter name (`param`) is lost in this case.

As you may notice, both methods deviate from the standard `Cookie` header format which expects *semicolon-separated* name=value pairs:

```
Cookie: [cookie-name]=[cookie-value]; [cookie-name]=[cookie-value];...
```

In other words, OpenAPI's *exploded* form of cookies is not quite compatible with cookie parsers. For example, an OpenAPI-formatted exploded array cookie `Cookie: param=3&param=4&param=5` would be parsed by a cookie parser as `param` = `3&param=4&param=5` - which is not what an API developer would expect.

The problems with cookie serialization are being discussed here:
[Default 'explode' for cookie parameters?](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/1528#issuecomment-379375751)

Feel free to provide your implementer's feedback.

Comment: You are a lifesaver @Helen, thanks very much, also for the references. I hope parameter serialization gets a second look, if there's ever an OpenAPI 4.